# Combo Box runs rowSource select on first use (open) but not on subsequent activations

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a master form (University) with sub-form (Students) list embedded.  I have some VBA to allow a New Student to load a StudentEntryForm using "DoCmd.OpenForm"

In the StudentEntryForm I have a ComboBox with a Row Source which retrieves the UniversityName (rather than showing the ID)

```
Control Source = UniversityID
Row Source = SELECT University.ID, University.Name FROM University;
```

and "On Activate" I'm setting the UniversityID field

```
Me.UniversityID = frmMaster.ID
```

If the StudentEntryForm is actually forced to Open (from Closed) then this works fine and the University name is shown in the combo box

However, next time I select New from the first sub-form the StudentEntryForm shows but with the University Name blank- "On Activate" runs.

Is there a way to force the Row Source to be "re-performed" ?

I have tried.

- Me.requery
- Me.UniversityCombo.refresh
- Me.refresh

Thanks

**Edit**: One other key difference is that - on first Load the next Student ID is assigned and showing - it appears a new record with this Id has been added, but on subsequent loads/activation the ID = "(New)".

Comment: Have you tried a `.requery` on the combo box?

Comment: Yes, no joy I'm afraid

Comment: Having failed to get what Access is doing here - it's probably my misunderstanding! - I have decided to always close the linked (Student) form (via Buttons on the linked form) and pass the University Id through on DoCmd.Load (OpenArgs) - seems to work, but perhaps not optimal

Answer (score 0):

When you select New on the SubForm, it should have this code line behind it:

```
Forms!MyMainForm!UniversityID.RecordSource = "SELECT University.ID, University.Name FROM University"
Forms!MyMainForm!UniversityID.Refresh
```

This way, any time that button is pressed, the record source for the combo will be updated.

Obviously, replace "MyMainForm" with your actual form name in the above code.

Comment: I assume you mean the sub form code should force the opened data on form (StudentsEntryForm) after the DoCmd.Open?  The Form!StudentsEntryForm is Null straight after the Open.

Comment: I have actually decided to go a different way on this - which I'll post in response - so don't sweat this.